# In Rust how can I define or import a C struct from a third party library?

Tags: rust

The Rust FFI guide (http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/guide-ffi.html) nicely demonstrates how to import C functions that use standard C types that are wrapped by the Rust `std::lib` library, such as `size_t`.  But how do I bring C data structures defined in third party libraries into a Rust program?

I'm working with [libmemcached](http://libmemcached.org/libMemcached.html), which has the following function:

```c
memcached_st* memcached_create(memcached_st *ptr)
```

which is typically invoked like so in a C program (to kick things off):

```c
#include <libmemcached/memcached.h>
// ...
memcached_st *memc;
memc = memcached_create(NULL);
```

The `memcached_st` is an opaque C struct - how do I declare and use that in a Rust program?  Here are my failed attempts so far:

```rust
use std::libc::*;
use ptr;

#[link(name = "memcached")]
extern {
    struct memcached_st;  // error: unexpected token: `struct`
    memcached_st* memcached_create(memcached_st *ptr);
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let memc = memcached_create(ptr:null());
        println!("{:?}", memc);
    }
}
```

and

```rust
use std::libc::*;
use ptr;

#[link(name = "memcached")]
extern {
    // error: unexpected token: `memcached_st`
    memcached_st* memcached_create(memcached_st *ptr);
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let memc = memcached_create(ptr:null());
        println!("{:?}", memc);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that using an empty enum is typically preferred to a unit-struct, as that way there is no constructor for it. Apart from that, it's much of a muchness.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using empty structure is a valid approach. You almost got it, you just don't need to put the struct definition in `extern` block. Also you can't use C code inside Rust sources - extern definitions have to follow standard Rust syntax.

```rust
use std::ptr;

struct memcached_st;

#[link(name = "memcached")]
extern {
    fn memcached_create(ptr: *memcached_st) -> *memcached_st;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let memc = memcached_create(ptr::null());
        println!("{:?}", memc);
    }
}
```

Comment: after updating to the current rust compiler (adding `const` to the pointer) this warns now about improper_ctypes