# C Abstract Data Type in Rust

Tags: c, rust, ffi, abstract-data-type

I have this code in my header file:

```
typedef struct _game* Game;
```

Right now to FFI from Rust I'm doing:

```
extern "C" {
    pub type Game = usize;
}
```

Is there a safer way to do this than to treat it like a pointer-sized numeric type? Would this work:

```
pub struct Game(usize);
```

Comment: Seems suspiciously similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116547/in-rust-how-can-i-define-or-import-a-c-struct-from-a-third-party-library however the answer to this question (by the same author) is more up-to-date vis a vis the guidelines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually model abstract C types in Rust using a pointer to an empty enum:

```rust
pub enum _game {}
pub type Game = *mut _game;
```

This approach explicitly highlights the fact that you cannot create values of `_game` yourself - you can only get a pointer to it from somewhere.

That said, if you're writing a more high-level wrapper for your library, you should wrap this `Game` into a more high-level `Game`, like this:

```rust
extern crate your_library_sys;

pub struct Game(your_library_sys::Game);
```

Here `your_library_sys` is a "sys" crate which contains low-level FFI bindings to the library. This is a convention which is [described](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#-sys-packages) in Cargo docs.