# How do I initialize an opaque C struct when using Rust FFI?

Tags: rust, ffi

Here's what I would like to do in C code:

```c
#include <some_lib.h>
int main() {
    some_lib_struct_t x;
    some_lib_func(&x);
}
```

How do I make use of the library in Rust? Here's what I've got so far:

```
extern crate libc; // 0.2.51

struct some_lib_struct_t;

#[link(name = "some_lib")]
extern "C" {
    fn some_lib_func(x: *mut some_lib_struct_t);
}

fn main() {
    let mut x: some_lib_struct_t;
    unsafe {
        some_lib_func(&mut x);
    }
}
```

When compiling I get an error:

```
error[E0381]: borrow of possibly uninitialized variable: `x`
  --> src/main.rs:13:23
   |
13 |         some_lib_func(&mut x);
   |                       ^^^^^^ use of possibly uninitialized `x`
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The safest answer is to initialize the struct yourself:

```
let mut x: some_lib_struct_t = some_lib_struct_t;
unsafe {
    some_lib_func(&mut x);
}
```

The closest analog to the C code is to use [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html)

```
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

unsafe {
    let mut x = MaybeUninit::uninit();
    some_lib_func(x.as_mut_ptr());
}
```

Before Rust 1.36, you can use [`mem::uninitialized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html):

```
unsafe {
    let mut x: some_lib_struct_t = std::mem::uninitialized();
    some_lib_func(&mut x);
}
```

You **have to be sure** that `some_lib_func` completely initializes all the members of the struct, otherwise the unsafety will leak outside of the `unsafe` block.

Speaking of "members of the struct", I can almost guarantee your code won't do what you want. You've defined `some_lib_struct_t` as having zero size. That means that no stack space will be allocated for it, and a reference to it won't be what your C code is expecting.

You need to mirror the definition of the C struct in Rust so that the appropriate size, padding, and alignment can be allocated. Usually, this means using `repr(C)`.

Many times, C libraries avoid exposing their internal struct representation by always returning a pointer to the opaque type:

- [What's the Rust idiom to define a field pointing to a C opaque pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38315383/155423)
- [In Rust how can I define or import a C struct from a third party library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22116547/155423)
- [Allocating an object for C / FFI library calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28154683/155423)

Comment: I got it working using mem::uninitialized(). But I get a warning from the compiler. I updated the question with more info.

Comment: @EFTH I've already addressed that. See the part of my answer talking about "zero size". If you have a *opaque pointer*, then see the 3 linked questions.

Comment: Note that `std::mem::uninitialized` is *Deprecated since 1.39.0: use `mem::MaybeUninit` instead*.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation for [`mem::uninitialized()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html):

> Deprecated since 1.39.0: use [`mem::MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html) instead

The new solution would look like this:

```rust
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

let instance = unsafe {
    let mut x: MaybeUninit<some_lib_struct_t> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
    some_lib_func(x.as_mut_ptr());
    x.assume_init()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43350455/155423), I looked closer at the header for the library. Just as they said, `some_lib_struct_t` was just a typedef for a pointer to `actual_lib_struct_t`. I made the following changes:

```
extern crate libc;

struct actual_lib_struct_t;
type some_lib_type_t = *mut actual_lib_struct_t;

#[link(name="some_lib")]
extern {
    fn some_lib_func(x: *mut some_lib_type_t);
}

fn main() {
    let mut x: some_lib_type_t;
    unsafe {
        x = std::mem::uninitialized();
        some_lib_func(&mut x);
    }
}
```

And it works! I do however get the warning `found zero-size struct in foreign module, consider adding a member to this struct, #[warn(improper_ctypes)] on by default`.